# ASP.NET: Авторизация пользователей в Identity. Тип сущности ApplicationUser не входит в модель для текущего контекста

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

Я делал точно такую же авторизацию очень давно с помощью Oracle и у меня успешно всё получилось, но делая её с помощью MSSQL столкнулся с проблемой. Опишу как я всё делал:
Создал IdentityConfig.cs и подставил туда все необходимые данные.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("PROJECTEntities", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Models.ApplicationDbContext>(null);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("PROJECT_SUL_USERS");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("PROJECT_SUL_ROLES");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("PROJECT_SUL_USER_ROLES");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("PROJECT_SUL_USER_CLAIMS");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("PROJECT_SUL_USER_LOGINS");

    }
}
```

Создал таблицы в MSSQL и присоединился к ней с помощью создания модели EF. Получилась такая строка подключения:

```
<add name="PROJECTEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ModelSUL.csdl|res://*/Models.ModelSUL.ssdl|res://*/Models.ModelSUL.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=23.4.1.231;initial catalog=PROJECT;persist security info=True;user id=PROJECT;password=password123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

При заходе на страницу авторизации никаких ошибок не выдаёт, но при авторизации выводи ошибку что ApplicationUser не входит в модель для текущего контекста.

```
    Тип сущности ApplicationUser не входит в модель для текущего контекста.
Описание: Необработанное исключение при выполнении текущего веб-запроса. Изучите трассировку стека для получения дополнительных сведений о данной ошибке и о вызвавшем ее фрагменте кода.

Сведения об исключении: System.InvalidOperationException: Тип сущности ApplicationUser не входит в модель для текущего контекста.

Ошибка источника:
    
    
    Строка 82:             // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    Строка 83:             // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    Строка 84:             var result = SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    Строка 85:             resultView = result.ToString();
    Строка 86:             switch (result)
    
    Исходный файл: C:\SVN\PROJECTMVC\SendingUniqueLinks\Controllers\AccountController.cs    Строка: 84
    
    Трассировка стека:
    
    
    [InvalidOperationException: Тип сущности ApplicationUser не входит в модель для текущего контекста.]
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType) +196
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +37
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +52
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
       System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +38
       System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +138
       System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +145
       Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__67.MoveNext() +402
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
       Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
       Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<PasswordSignInAsync>d__24.MoveNext() +309
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
       Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func`1 func) +175
       Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManagerExtensions.PasswordSignIn(SignInManager`2 manager, String userName, String password, Boolean isPersistent, Boolean shouldLockout) +127
       SendingUniqueLinks.Controllers.<Login>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\SVN\PROJECTMVC\SendingUniqueLinks\Controllers\AccountController.cs:84
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__11_0() +50
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3() +35
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
       System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
       System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
       System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9873933
       System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
       System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159Т
```

Я понимаю что ошибка скорее всего в строке конфига БД, но не могу понять где и как это исправить.

Comment: я бы сделал через CodeFirst и автоматическую накрутку Identity через студию и сравнил что внутри и что не так прописано у вас

Comment: У меня вызывают сомнения несколько мест в коде: я не делал GenerateUserIdentityAsync в кастомном классе ApplicationUser, я не помню, есть ли перегрузка `: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` (мнится мне, что придётся сразу автоматом и UserRole кастомить - все примеры они были `: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, UserRole>`), строка подключения должна быть иной - такое впечатление, что взята от очень старой версии EF 6 Model First. Также я присоединяюсь к предыдущему оратору: создайте пустой проект по шаблону и посмотрите, в чём различие вашего проекта с типовым.

Comment: Настораживает меня вот этот шаг: *"Создал таблицы в MSSQL и присоединился к ней с помощью создания модели EF. "* У вас **уже** есть модель внутри `ApplicationDbContext` , зачем вы создали ещё одну? И почему вообще у вас в одном проекте оказались EF Core и EF 6 одновременно?